# Search for my magento returning error. catalogsearch_fulltext is read only

Tags: catalogsearch, table

General error: 1036 Table 'catalogsearch_fulltext' is read only. Can't use the search function.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like ownership problem. Who owns /var/db/mysql?

```
chown -Rf mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/DBNAME
```

Restart mysql

Comment: its owned by mysql:mysql

Comment: still need to apply that command even tho it's owned by mysql?